# javascript input.focus() is not working in firefox 23

Tags: javascript, css, validation, input, focus

I am using this code..
Error is showing but focus is not working in firefox. As this code is working in IE, i can't say this code is completely wrong.

```
<form name="frm" action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" onblur="return check();"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
<strong id="err"></strong>
</form>
```

I am using this string in external javascript.

This code is in valid.js

```
function check()
{
 var item=frm.search;
 var errr=document.getElementById('err');

 if(item.value.length<3)
 {
 item.focus();
 errr.innerHTML="Entered String is very short";
 return false;
 }
}
```

Please reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: Any error in Developer console / Firebug ?

Comment: I've used this code in many firefox versions from different computers but result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
function check()
{
var item = document.forms['frm'].elements['search'];
 var errr=document.getElementById('err');

 if(item.value.length<3)
 {
 errr.innerHTML="Entered String is very short";
    setTimeout(function() {
    item.focus()
}, 10);
 return false;
 }
}
```

demo jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ff4vW/

Comment: Is there any require to use jquery for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its good if you use document.getElementById()

But if you are using name
Then you should use

```
 var item = document.forms['frm'].elements['search'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = document.getElementsByName('search')[0];
```

Comment: It should work fine. What errors are you seeing in the console?

Comment: Whoops. A little mistake on my end. Fixed now. You should have seen an error with that previous code, though.